# Sorting nested lists of variable length in Python

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I have a nested list of varying length, for which I would like to sort by each index alphabetically. That it to say, I have:

```
a = [['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
     ['apple',   'pear',    'banana' ],
     ['pear',    'banana',  'orange' ],
     ['kiwi',     None,     'apple'  ],
     ['peach',    None,      None   ]]
```

I'd like an operation to output the following:

```
a = [['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
     ['apple',   'banana',  'apple'  ],
     ['kiwi',    'pear',    'banana' ],
     ['peach',    None,     'orange' ],
     ['pear',     None,      None   ]]
```

I've tried using nested for loops to go through and create temporary lists of values for a specific index, before sorting and then re-adding, however appear to be getting an index error (maybe due to the None values)?

Would be good to understand if nested loops is the most efficient way to do this. I had originally used `itemgetter` to sort the nested list, but then had to transpose them, and used `map(lambda *row: list(row), *a)` to do so - this didn't preserve my ordering though.

As far as I can see, I can't use `itemgetter` on the now transposed nested lists without preserving indexes across the nested lists.

Comment: Also you're missing some commas. Try pasting what you've got into a python console and checking that it works.

Comment: `sorted` builtin with a custom comparer will do just fine, and generator expressions should be handier than temporary lists. Errors while "re-adding" appear to be some trivial mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zip splats (`zip(*a)`) is a good way to convert rows to columns. Then sort the columns and convert back. The only problem is that you can't compare `None` to `str`, so you'll have to define some custom sorting algorithm, e.g.:

```
def sorter(char):
    if char is None:
        return chr(0x101111) # largest character
        # this is certainly a kludge solution, but I can't
        # find a better one in the minimal time I have to research
        # hopefully comments will find better!
    else:
        return char

a = [['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
     ['apple',   'pear',    'banana' ],
     ['pear',    'banana',  'orange' ],
     ['kiwi',     None,     'apple'  ],
     ['peach',    None,      None    ]]

a_headers, a_rows = a[0], a[1:]
a_to_columns = list(zip(*a_rows))
sorted_a_columns = [sorted(lst, key=sorter) for lst in a_to_columns]
result = [a_headers] + list(map(list, zip(*sorted_a_columns))))

>>> pprint(result)

[['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
 ['apple'  , 'banana' , 'apple'  ],
 ['kiwi'   , 'pear'   , 'banana' ],
 ['peach'  ,  None    , 'orange' ],
 ['pear'   ,  None    ,  None    ]]
```